# Need Google script to stop running script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am currently running a Google Apps Script which helps me to execute a function automatically once the sheet is open. But I don't want it runs automatically ALWAYS. Sometimes I want NOT TO run the script, and I want to call another function which will kill the automatically running one or all the functions temporary until I Open the file again.

Here is the function is run automatically, and bottom is the  function I want to call to kill or stop the `onSelectionChange()` function:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
const previousSheet = prop.getProperty("previousSheet");
const range = e.range;
//const a1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
const sheetName = range.getSheet().getSheetName();
if (sheetName != previousSheet && sheetName=="Balance Life Today") {

BalanceLifeTodayUpdate();

}else if (sheetName != previousSheet && sheetName=="Values Power Success") {

ValuesPowerSuccessUpdate();


}else if (sheetName != previousSheet && sheetName=="To-Do List") {

ToDoListUpdate();


}

prop.setProperty("previousSheet", sheetName);
}





function stopScript() {
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('STOP');
return 'Kill Signal Issued';
}
```

Comment: Do you have any specific criteria that you want to use to run one script or another?

Comment: Remove the onOpen and use a button or a menu item

Answer (score 0):

Here is an onOpen() that I use to add menu items.  I added some commands after that.  If the day of the week is Saturday it will not run anything beyond that command.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Test");
  menu.addItem("Show Test","showTest");
  menu.addItem("Run Test","runTest");
  menu.addToUi();
  let today = new Date();
  today = today.getDay();
  if( today === 6 ) return;  // if today is Saturday do nothing
  // do what ever else you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('STOP');
```

`setProperty` requires two parameters, the property name and the property value.

Also your `onSelectChange` function doesn't read this property. You should add a statement to read it. Once this function has the 'STOP' value, you might use a if statement to force the "exit". I.E. you might add the following statement after `const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();` (assuming that the value that the property name is `'STOP'` and the value to exit is `'yes'`.

```
if(prop.getProperty('STOP') === 'yes') return;
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setpropertykey,-value

Comment: I messed up everything here '


       function stopScript() {
       PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('STOP');
       const prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
       if(prop.getProperty('STOP') === 'yes') return;
       }